# R, .Call function, and SEXP structures

Tags: c, r

I am building a package in R with a very specific Simulated Annealing algorithm for my problem, and I have a doubt regarding C code and SEXP that I haven't been able to solve. I am not an expert in R, I have been working with it for only 3 weeks... but I have to do this.

As far as I know, the `.Call` function in R passes the parameters as a SEXP structure to C by reference (i.e. they are not duplicated). Am I right? What if I have another function in C called from the first function in C that needs this SEXP structure? (See example). I am asking because one of these parameters is quite big and uses a lot of space (10^7 ~ 10^18 doubles, although I don't use them all in every iteration) and I will call this function quite a lot of times, so if each time I call it this parameter gets duplicated I will run out of memory.

MWE:

R call

```
MySimAn <- function(def_energy, i_pos, T0, Tfinal){
  ret <- .Call("CMySimAn",def_energy, i_pos, T0, Tfinal, seq0)
  ret
}
```

C functions

```
double Energy(SEXP def_energy, SEXP seq0, int i0){
  int i;
  double res=0;
  for(i=0;i<INTEGER(GET_DIM(seq0))[0];i++){
    res += NUMERIC(def_energy)[i0+INTEGER(seq0)[i]];
  }
  return(res);
}

SEXP CmySimAn(SEXP def_energy, SEXP i_pos, SEXP T0, SEXP Tfinal, SEXP seq0){
  SEXP = Ene;
  PROTECT(Ene = NEW_NUMERIC(1));
  REAL(Ene)[0] = Energy(def_energy, seq0, INTEGER(i_pos));
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return Ene;
}
```

Would something like this work (the code in the function `Energy` is not checked so might be wrong)? Would I be creating a duplicate of def_energy each time I call it, whether in R or C? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code is nearly (syntactically) correct as written, and there is no memory copying; the arguments passed to C from R should be treated as 'read only'.

A common paradigm is to write an R / C interface layer, with any functions called from that layer in pure (non-R) C. So

```
double Energy(const double *def_energy, const int *seq0, int dim0, int i0)
{
  int i;
  double res=0;
  for(i = 0; i < dim0; i++) {
    res += def_energy[i0 + seq0[i]];
  }
  return(res);
}
```

Use `const` to enforce the implicit contract that the values passed from R should not be written to. With the R / C wrapper

```
SEXP CmySimAn(SEXP def_energy, SEXP i_pos, SEXP T0, SEXP Tfinal, SEXP seq0){
  double Ene = Energy(REAL(def_energy), INTEGER(seq0), INTEGER(GET_DIM(seq0)[0]),
                      INTEGER(i_pos)[0]);
  return ScalarReal(Ene);
}
```

The accessor for numeric elements is `REAL()` (you used `NUMERIC` in Energy). Your use of `PROTECT(...); REAL(Ene)[0] = ...; UNPROTECT(Ene);` was correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, all the "internal" C functions called in pure C. The `INTEGER(i_pos)[0]` is because `INTEGER(i_pos)` is a pointer, am I right?

Comment: Yes, the accessors `INTEGER()`, `REAL()` are all returning points.